# Categorical Proof for Constructing Homogeneous Spaces?

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, category-theory, smooth-manifolds, homogeneous-spaces

I have a specific question with a broader question attached to it.

**Part 1**

Homogeneous spaces are defined as smooth manifolds endowed with a transitive action from a Lie group.  In the event that $G\times M \to M$ is a smooth transitive action, then $M\cong G/G_p$ where $G_p$ is the isotropy subgroup of the point $p\in M$.  Remarkably though, we find that any time we find that a Lie group $G$ acts transitively on a *set* $X$, and as long as $G_p \subseteq G$ is closed for some $p \in X$ we find that $X$ is a smooth manifold with a homogeneous structure.

I'm new to category theory, but with the basic knowledge of functors, limits, and colimits, this theorem feels like it has a deeply categorical flavor to it.  For instance, if we let $\mathsf{Lie}$ be the category with Lie groups and Lie group homomomorphisms, $\mathsf{Diff}$ the category of smooth manifolds and $C^\infty$ mappings between manifolds, and $\mathsf{Set}$ the category of sets and mappings, then to me the above theorem *appears* that it could be rephrased in the following way:

Given any functor $F:\mathsf{B}G \to \mathsf{Set}$ for $\mathsf{B}G$ the associated monoid of a Lie group $G \in \text{Ob}(\mathsf{Lie})$ such that the colimit colim $F$ is a singleton, then we have that this functor $F$ lifts to a functor $\widetilde{F}:\mathsf{B}G \to \mathsf{Diff}$ such that the commutative diagram holds:

[image]

Where $U$ here is the forgetful functor.  The condition that colim $F$ be singleton is equivalent to the fact that functors from a monoid to $\mathsf{Set}$ essentially assign group actions from the underlying group, and the colimit of this functor is essentially the orbit space of the set being acted upon.  Therefore transitivity of the action is equivalent to colim $F \cong \{*\}$.  **Is such a categorical proof possible and what machinery is needed to prove such a statement?**

**Part 2**

To me a key part of the above observation (if it's valid) is learning (re-learning?) mathematical subjects from a fundamentally categorical view.  There are obviously a lot of texts on category theory itself, and a lot of good topology books that view the subject from a strictly categorical perspective (e.g. Peter May's *Concise Course*).  **Are there any good books/articles for learning/re-learning classical differentiable geometry from the categorical perspective?  Other books that attempt to revamp a part of mathematics from a categorical perspective, aside from topology?  I'd be interested in learning of analysis, measure theory, Hilbert and Banach spaces from this perspective if literature exists on the topic.**  I know that algebraic geometry deeply employs categories, but I'm broadly unfamiliar with this subject (for now).

Comment: The transitivity of the action is, I think, actually not the most important part of theorem. (For instance, one can easily generalise to the case where $M$ is a disjoint union of orbits.) It is far more important that the quotient $G / G_p$ has a manifold structure, and this is related to the condition that $G_p$ be a closed subgroup of $G$.

Comment: @ZhenLin It's true that this is a necessary condition in the theorem, and one that doesn't seem to be captured by any of the category-theoretic descriptions I have above.  Maybe there's an additional condition of the form $\mathsf{B}G \to \mathsf{Top}$?

Comment: Other than the fact that some of the theorem can be rephrased categorically, what makes you think that there should be a categorical proof ? As Zhen Lin points out, this theorem (and its usual proofs) hinges a lot on topological structure

Comment: @MaximeRamzi Honestly, my reason for believing so may just be naivet$\acute{\text{e}}$.  I'm rather inexperienced in the subject, but my understanding of category theory is that it's a more general framework for mathematics and is therefore more powerful and far-reaching.  Because I intuited a categorical description of this theorem, it made me question whether the result could be attributed to categorical reasoning (not just a description).  I take it that category theory is more often a generalizing framework and language, not necessarily an efficient means of proof?

Comment: Sometimes it can be an efficient means for proofs; but definitely not all the time. Some proofs or results are just *not* categorical in nature, you have to have some other input. Category theory can help organizing thought and proofs, and reduce proofs a lot (because often, a big chunk of a proof *is* categorical) but there is often a non-category theoretic core which cannot be avoided.

Comment: @MaximeRamzi I figured that was the case in general: specific results rely on constructions that are not categorical.  I thought that in the present case that lifting is such a generic process in mathematics that there might have been a possibility of a category-theoretic proof.